# Is it a leak if memory isn't freed in a child process before exit?

Tags: c, fork, valgrind, child-process, execve

There are similar question all over and one which is closes is from [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140483/is-it-a-waste-of-time-to-free-resources-before-i-exit-a-process/140523) stack exchange site. But even tho I learned a lot reading them none of them a exactly answer my question.

Here is the question, say I have this program (it is a very simplified version)

```
inline void execute(char *cmd)
{
    int exitstat = 0;
    //lots of other thins happed
    exitstat = execve(cmd, cmdarg, environ);
    free(cmd), free(other passed adress);  ## DO I NEED THIS, since I am already about to exit
    _exit (exitstat);
}

int main(void)
{
    int childstat;
    char *str = malloc(6); //I also have many more allocated space in heap in the parent process
    strcpy(str, "Hello");

    pid_t childid = fork() //creat a child process, which will also get a copy of all the heap memories even tho it is CoW.
    if (childid < 0)
        exit(-1);
    if (child == 0)
    {
        execute(str);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&childstat);
        free(str);
    }


//do somethign else with str with other functions and the rest of the program
}
```

In this program, the `parent` `process` does its thing for a while, allocates a lot of process in the `heap`, `free` some, keep other for later and at some point it wants to execute some command, but it doesn't want to terminate, so it creates a `child` to do its biting.

The child then calls another function which will do some task and in the end use `execve` to `execute` the command passed to it. If this was successful there would be no problem, since the executed program will handle all the allocated spaces, but if it failed the child exits with a status code. The  parent waits for the child to answer, and when it does it moves on to its next routine. The problem here is that when the `child` fails to execute all the heap data remains allocated, but does that matter? since,

1. it is about to be exited int he next line,
2. Even though I am getting started with this, I have learned that a new `process` is created during `fork`, so the memory leak shouldn't affect the `parent` since the `child` is about to die.
3. If my assumption is correct and this leaks doesn't actually matter, why does `valgrind` lament about them?
4. Would there be a better way to `free` all the memories in the child heap with out actually passing all the memores (`str,` and the others in this example) to the execute function and laboriously call `free` each time? does `kill()` have a mechanism for this?

**Edit**

Here is working code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

inline void execute(char *cmd)
{
    extern char **environ;
    int exitstat = 0;
    char *cmdarg[2];
    cmdarg[0] = cmd;
    cmdarg[1] = NULL;
    exitstat = execve(cmd, cmdarg, environ);
    free(cmd);
    _exit (exitstat);
}

int main(void)
{
    int childstat;
    char *str = malloc(6);
    pid_t  childid;

    strcpy(str, "Hello");
    childid = fork();
    if (childid < 0)
        exit(-1);
    if (childid == 0)
    {
        execute(str);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&childstat);
        free(str);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

When there is a free inside the child process here is valgrinds result.
[image]

When run with the `free` inside the child process is commented.(`#free(cmd)` in the execute function).

[image]

As you might see there is no overall error ([image]) since this programm is short lived. But in my real program which has an infinite loop every problem in the child ([image]) matters. So I was asking if I be worried by this leaked memories in this child process just before exiting and hunt them down or just leave them as they are in another virtual space and they are cleaned as their processes exit (but in that case why is valgrind still complaining about them if their corresponding process clean them during exit)

Comment: Please create a full _compilable_ [MCVE], including all the stuff. Guessing all needed `#include` is no fun. `child` is undefined. There is `;` missing after `fork()`. The presented code may/will not compile because of `inline`. After fixing all the mistakes, I cannot reproduce the "valgrind lamenting about memory leaks". He does not "lament" about it.

Comment: @KamilCuk, my bad I am sorry, not just for you, finding the write libs was no fun even for me. Thanks! (I have fixed it!) . And valgrind is still "lamenting:)"

Comment: Yes, you get a leak, because `execve` returns with an error, as expected. I doubt you have a command named `Hello` on your machine.

Comment: @KamilCuk, So my question is , will this matter if the program is going to run for a very long time? Won't the OS handel those leakes (during child exit) even before the parent process exits? If it doesn't, wouldn't that mean the parent process in theory will run out of heap to allocate because the child processes keep leaking it? And if this is the problem what is the best way to free memory in child (you have already answered me this one)?

Comment: `the parent process in theory will run out of heap to allocate because the child processes keep leaking it?` That makes no sense. No, parent and child are separate unrelated processes with unrelated memory. `will this matter if the program is going to run for a very long time?` if the child doesn't exit right after `execve`, then there will be unused memory. `Won't the OS handel those leakes (during child exit) even before the parent process exits?` Parent process is unrelated. OS always handles all memory of all processes. When child exits, the memory is managed by OS

Comment: OK, Thank you so much now that make sense, just one more question. I read some where that says unless the parent is waiting for the child processes to return they become a zombie and they won't be killed until the parent dies, would the  memory leak affect in such a case since the os won't be handling this processes

Comment: No, that's unrelated. Because child already died, so all resources that were held by the child are returned to OS. Information about zombie processes is stored inside OS by OS in some special structure managed by OS unrelated to whatever was going on inside the process. `they won't be killed until the parent dies` A zombie process is dead, that's why it's a "zombie". Your description of zombie doesn't make sense.

Comment: `the parent is waiting for the child processes to return they become a zombie` No. When the parent is __not__ waiting for the child process and the parent is continuing to run and the child process has exited, then the child process becomes a zombie. A zombie is there, because parent needs to be notified with that the child process exited. Until parent does that, receives that notification that child process died, that information needs to be stored inside OS. That state of the child with a waiting notification to be delivered to parent about a dead child - is called "zombie".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> exitstat = execve(cmd, cmdarg, environ);
> free(cmd), free(other passed adress);
> ```

If successful, `execve` *does not return*. No code is executed after it, the execution is terminated and the `cmd` process is started. All memory hold by current process is freed anyway by the operating system. The code `free(cmd), free(other passed adress);` *will not execute* if `execve` call is successful.

The only case where those liens could be relevant are in case of `execve` error. And in case `execve` returns with an error, yes, you should free that memory. I much doubt most programs with `execve` actually do that and I believe they would just call `abort()` after failed `execve` call.

> ```
> inline void execute(char *cmd)
> ```

Please read about `inline`. `inline` is tricky. I recommend not use it, forget it exists. I doubt the intention here is to make an inline function - there is no other function the compiler can choose from anyway. After fixing typos in code, I could not compile the code because of undefined reference to `execute` - `inline` has to be removed.

> The problem here is that when the child fails to execute all the heap data remains allocated, but does that matter?

Ultimately it depends on what do *you* want to do after the child fails. If you want to just call `exit` and you do not care about memory leaks in such case, then just don't care and it will not matter.

I see [glibc exec*.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/posix/execle.c#L26) functions try to avoid dynamic allocation as much as possible and use variable length arrays or `alloca()`.

> If my assumption is correct and this leaks doesn't actually matter, why does valgrind lament about them?

It doesn't. If you correct all the mistakes in your code, then `valgrind` will not "lament" about memory leaks before calling `execve` (well, unless the `execve` call fails).

> Would there be a better way to free all the memories in the child heap with out actually passing all the memores (str, and the others in this example) to the execute function and laboriously call free each time?

"Better" will tend to be opinion based. Subjectively: no. But writing/using own wrapper around dynamic allocation with garbage collector to free all memory is also an option.

> does kill() have a mechanism for this?

No, sending a signal seems unrelated to freeing memory.

Comment: "And in case `execve` returns with an error, yes, you should free that memory. I much doubt most programs with `execve` actually do that and I believe they would just call `abort()` after failed `execve` call." Why do you want programs to bother freeing any memory if they're about to exit? All that accomplishes is making it take longer for them to exit. To quote Raymond Chen, "[The building is being demolished. Don’t bother sweeping the floor and emptying the trash cans and erasing the whiteboards.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120105-00/?p=8683)"

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica. But wouldn't that affect the parent process if the program is going to run for a very long time

Comment: No, it would not. These are separate processes.

Comment: Ok, dose this mean the os will clean up the child processes allocated the mems as soon as it exits. if that is the case why is valgrind considering it as a leak?

Comment: Os will __always__ clean up after the process. Because that is a leak - resource was not cleaned up by the process.

Comment: @EHM It technically is a leak, but the reasons that leaks are usually bad are that resources are held longer than necessary or usage keeps growing over time, but neither of those apply to this particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution.

On termination, the OS will free all memory for a process. That means that you don't *have* to free everything. However, for memory that is no longer needed it is usually best to free it as soon as possible. That leaves things like buffers that could potentially be used right up to the last moment before termination.

Reasons to free memory.

1. There's only one that I can think of. If you have a large number of blocks in use at the end it can be difficult to sort the wheat from the chaff. Either you end up with enormous logs that no-one looks at, or you have to maintain a suppression file. Either way you risk overlooking genuine issues.

Reasons not to free memory

1. Small performance gain
2. It can be quite difficult sometimes to free everything. For instance if you use `putenv()` then knowing whether the string was added (and needs freeing) or replaced (must not be freed) is a bit tricky.
3. If you need to use `atexit()` to free things, then there is a limit on the number of functions that you can call via `atexit()`. That might be a problem if you have many things being freed in many modules.

My advice is try to free most things but don't sweat it or you'll get bitten by the law of diminishing returns. Use a suppression file judiciously for the few percent that are tricky to free.